# Is it possible to make this nested for loop less than O(N^2)?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, big-o

I am working on a Kafka Streaming service using Apache Spark 2.1 and Java 8. I use a nested `for` loop to populate an `ArrayList` with Topic/Partition pairs.

Is it possible to reduce this nested `for` loop from O(N^2) using another methodology?

Here is the code:

```
    private static List<TopicAndPartition> createTAndPList(List<String> topics, List<String> partitions)
        throws ConsumerException {
    if (topics.size() != partitions.size()) {
        throw new ConsumerException("Cannot create list with unequal number of topics and parititons,");
    }

    List<TopicAndPartition> topicsAndPartitions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int t = 0; t < topics.size(); t++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < Integer.parseInt(partitions.get(t)); p++) {
            topicsAndPartitions.add(new TopicAndPartition(topics.get(t), p));
        }
    }

    return topicsAndPartitions;
}
```

FYI: I am prevented from using above Kafka 8 due to powers beyond my control (management.)

Comment: Does this code get called a lot? if this is just initializing some data and happens once... then I'd just go with this straight forward approach.

Comment: Each nested loop adds one element to the list so I don't see how you propose to reduce the complexity, unless you don't need all the elements to be added?

Comment: If the correct result is an ArrayList with N^2 elements, it will take O(n^2) to fill it.

Comment: I agree with each comment. This code is only called when the streaming service is started, re-started, or if there is an update regarding the topic/partitions. Since it is a streaming service this may be daily, or monthly. This question was posed to me in a pull request by a senior reviewer, and I cannot think of another way to do it. Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: Can't you just use `int p = Integer.parseInt(partitions.get(t)); topicsAndPartitions.add(new TopicAndPartition(topics.get(t), p));` ? Maybe find a way that doesn't require the other 0..p-1entries.

Comment: @yacc Sadly I need all 0..p-1 entries for offset management. If I could upgrade to Kafka 10 or higher I could utilize the native offset management, but that is not an option at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your given code, it does not look possible to reduce the order.

However, there may be two small optimizations you can make.

- Move *topics.get(t)* out of the inner for loop,
- Do not recalculate the inner for loop termination condition every loop.

  ```
  for (int t = 0; t < topics.size(); t++) {
      String topic = topics.get(t);
      int count = Integer.parseInt(partitions.get(t));    
      for (int p = 0; p < count; p++) {
          topicsAndPartitions.add(new TopicAndPartition(topic, p));
  ```

You are calling *topics.get* and *Integer.parseInt(partitions.get(t))* t*p times instead of just t times.  The change of topics.get() will probably not do much, but moving something out of the inner loop like this is a pretty common optimization.

Finally, do you really need them all in a list?  Or can you generate them dynamically where you actually need them?

Comment: Good point moving ``Integer.parseInt(partitions.get(t));`` from the inner loop. Sadly I do need every element in the list.